# Swift 2 - kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813 using ssl

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ssl, alamofire

I am trying to access the data from my server using Alamofire. I have tried to edit the info.plist in all possible way but I cannot have a response from the link "https://plus.livectlab.com//users_videos.json".

If I use Http and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` I can get a response. My certificate is using SHA-2 and the error I get is:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://plus.livectlab.com//users_videos.json")

        .responseJSON { response in

            print(response.result) 
        }
```

> alamofireTest[1337:366916] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load
>   failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Any Idea why is this happening and how to avoid the security and use my https links?

Comment: could it be the extra slash in `https://plus.livectlab.com//users_videos.json`

Comment: I get a response if I use https://graph.facebook.com why?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [issue](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/876) as well as the new [ATS section](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#app-transport-security) in our README. You most likely are having issues with `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` and `NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy`. Both are described in-depth in the issue as well as the README.